# How to iterate through a list of tuples and make pairs out of them?

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples, append

I have a list like this:

```
point_list = [(54,8),(55,9),(56,10),(57,11)]
```

and now I want to make them as pairs like:

```
[(54,8),(55,9)],[(55,9),(56,10)],[(56,10),(57,11)],[(57,11),(54,8)]
```

and I have a function which takes in 2 point coordinates and returns the distance between them. How can I pass the individual pairs into the function and append all the distance together?

I did try to get the tuples into a list and now I am stuck on how to move forward from there to pass the pairs as arguments and append the distances.

Comment: what result do you seek if `point_list` contains only one or two tuples?

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension like so:

```py
point_list = [(54,8),(55,9),(56,10),(57,11)]

split_points = [[point_list[i], point_list[(i+1) % len(point_list)]] for i in range(len(point_list))]

print(split_points)
```

Output:

```py
[[(54, 8), (55, 9)], [(55, 9), (56, 10)], [(56, 10), (57, 11)], [(57, 11), (54, 8)]]
```

As suggested by @JonSG, the previous method with splicing would work with an extra append:

```py
point_list = [(54,8),(55,9),(56,10),(57,11)]

split_points = [point_list[i:i+2] for i in range(len(point_list)-1)]
split_points.append([point_list[-1], point_list[0]])

print(split_points)
```

To use the pairs of points, you could do something like this:

```py
def print_coordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    print(x1, x2, y1, y2)

for point1, point2 in split_points:
    print_coordinates(*point1, *point2)
```

Comment: Would it be easier to do your original then `split_points.append([point_list[-1], point_list[0]])
`?

Comment: Yes, but I like to keep my assignments tidy and do it all in one go rather than fix the incomplete structure. But I do see the reasons why that would be better.